# Express - Validation failed Passwords are not same in Login request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having an issue of validation in login request where no validation occurs. I want to append jwt token to a user but it ends up validation error and token is not appending.

Here is my controller

```
try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // Check if email and password exists
    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        status: 'Bad Request',
        message: `${!email ? 'Please enter email' : 'Please enter password'}`,
      });
    }

    // Check if user exists
    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 'Bad Request',
        message: 'User not found',
      });
    } else if (!(await user.comparePassword(password, user.password))) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 'Bad Request',
        message: 'Password wrong. Please enter correct password',
      });
    }

    // If everything ok, then create jwt token
    const token = signToken(user._id);
    // console.log({ token, user });

    // Append token in user's token array
    ///////// problem occurs here //////////
    user.appendToken(token);
    /* user.tokens.push({ token });
    await user.save(); */

    // Send token to client
    return res.status(200).json({
      status: 'Success',
      token,
      data: { user },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      status: 'Error',
      message: err,
    });
  }
```

appendToken function is just appending token to a user.

```
userSchema.methods.appendToken = async function (token) {
  const user = this;
  user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({ token });
  await user.save();
  return token;
};
```

As you can see I have a save query here, so I thought that is make trouble because I have a pre-save middleware in model but I'm wrong here too.

and my model is

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
  password_confirm: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
    validate: {
      validator: function (val) {
        return val === this.password;
      },
      message: 'Passwords are not same',
    },
  },
  role: { type: String, enum: ['admin', 'user', 'other'], required: true },
  profile_picture: { type: String, default: '' },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  address: { type: String, default: '' },
  dob: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    //required: true
  },
  age: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  gender: { type: String, enum: ['male', 'female'], required: true },
  description: { type: String, default: '' },
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  tokens: [
    {
      token: {
        type: String,
        // required: true
      },
    },
  ],
});
userSchema.pre(
  'save',
  // Hash password
  async function (next) {
    if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();
    // this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 8);
    this.password = cryptr.encrypt(this.password);
    this.password_confirm = undefined;
    next();
  }
);
```

I have a pre-save middleware in model. I thought it makes trouble for code but after commenting it, nothing happened and the problem is same as before. Every time I make login request, it ends up ValidationError at console but response has user data but not appended token in an array.

[image]

I don't know where I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: You shouldn't store the `password_confirm` field in the schema but only use it to validate the user's password on the signup call

Comment: Yeah, so in order to use it to validate user's password should I use it on the frontend?

Comment: You should use a validator library like `express-validator` to validate the `signup` call parameters and not store the `password_confirm` field in the database